# Expose port 80 and 443 on Google Container Engine without load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

Currently I'm working on a small hobby project which I'll make open source once it's ready. This service is running on Google Container Engine.
I chose GCE to avoid configuration hassle, the costs are affordable and to learn new stuff.

My pods are running fine and I created a service with type `LoadBalancer` to expose the service on port 80 and 443. This works perfectly.

However, I discovered that for each `LoadBalancer` service, a new Google Compute Engine load balancer is created. This load balancer pretty expensive and really over done for a hobby project on a single instance.

To cut the costs I'm looking for a way to expose the ports without the load balancer.

**What i've tried so far:**

- Deploy a `NodePort` service. Unfortunately it's disallowed to expose a
  port below 30000.
- Deploy an Ingress but this also creates a load balancer.
- Tried to disable `HttpLoadBalancing` (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#HttpLoadBalancing) but it still creates a load balancer.

Is there a way to expose port 80 and 443 for a single instance on Google Container Engine without a load balancer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, through externalIPs on the service. Example service I've used:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bind
  labels:
    app: bind
    version: 3.0.0
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
  selector:
    app: bind
    version: 3.0.0
  externalIPs:
    - a.b.c.d
    - a.b.c.e
```

Please be aware that the IPs listed in the config file must be the internal IP on GCE.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I missed something. The service is deployed but unable from the internet. I set the correct firewall rules. The service is displaying the correct `externalIp`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, forgot that I spent time on the exact same issue. The IPs listed need to be the **internal** IP, not external (At least on GCE).

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upvote yet... I dropped this comment to let you know that this answer combined with the comment above (which was the key) solved my issue!

Comment: Would you (or @RubenErnst)  mind expanding on the answer a bit? In particular, "the IPs listed on GCE must be the intrenal IP." Which IP do you mean? Are you able to get this working with a static IP assigned to your single node cluster?

Comment: @Brett: Sorry for my late response. Is your question already answered in the meantime?

Comment: @RubenErnst Thank you for following up. I wound up needing a LoadBalancer anyway so I didn't pursue it much.

Comment: How do I know the `internalIP` at this stage? Is it node IP or pod IP? If it's node then what if I have multiple nodes? If it's pod IP, is there a chance my pod IP will change in time?

Comment: It is internal IP of your instance in GCE under https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

Comment: I agree with @Brett. This is not a full-fledged solution, yet. The internal node IPs are ephemeral. Eventually, the website/webservice will go down because the service will point to a node IP that no longer exists. Until this can be made to work with a *true, static* external IP, it is a ticking bomb.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to ConnorJC's great and working solution: The same solution is also described in this question:
[Kubernetes - can I avoid using the GCE Load Balancer to reduce cost?](https://serverfault.com/questions/863569/kubernetes-can-i-avoid-using-the-gce-load-balancer-to-reduce-cost/869453#869453?newreg=8d728d4f3e474336b69e84c2a3994f5d)

The "internalIp" refers to the compute instance's (a.k.a. the node's) internal ip (as seen on Google Cloud Platform -> Google Compute Engine -> VM Instances)

This [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22294#issuecomment-191586390) gives a hint at why the internal and not the external ip should be configured.

Furthermore, after having configured the service for ports 80 and 443, I had to create a firewall rule allowing traffic to my instance node:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create your-name-for-this-fw-rule --allow tcp:80,tcp:443 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

After this setup, I could access my service through http(s)://externalIp

Comment: Using the node internal IP did the trick.   Such confusion with the naming!

Answer (score 2):

If you only have exactly one pod, you can use `hostNetwork: true` to achieve this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: caddy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: caddy
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true # <---------
      containers:
      - name: caddy
        image: your_image
        env:
        - name: STATIC_BACKEND # example env in my custom image
          value: $(STATIC_SERVICE_HOST):80
```

Note that by doing this **your pod will inherit the host's DNS resolver** and not Kubernetes'. That means you can no longer resolve cluster services by DNS name. For example, in the example above you cannot access the `static` service at http://static. You still can access services by their cluster IP, which are injected by [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables).

This solution is better than using service's externalIP as it bypass kube-proxy, and you will receive the correct source IP.

Answer (score 2):

To synthesize @ConnorJC @derMikey's answers into exactly what worked for me:

Given a cluster pool running on the **Compute Engine Instance**:

```
# gcloud compute instances list
gce vm name: gke-my-app-cluster-pool-blah`
internal ip: 10.123.0.1
external ip: 34.56.7.001 # will be publically exposed
```

I made the service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app-service
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.22.222.222
  externalIPs:
  - 10.123.0.1 # the instance internal ip
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app
  type: ClusterIP
```

and then opened the firewall for all(?) ips in the project:

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules create open-my-app --allow tcp:80,tcp:443 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

and then `my-app` was accessible via the **GCE Instance Public IP `34.56.7.001`** (not the cluster ip)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use the cloud load balancers, until necessary, because of cost and vendor lock-in.

Instead I use this: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

It's a pod that runs a load balancer for you. That page has GKE specific installation notes.

Comment: I have some bad news for you. `nginx-ingress` creates a load balancer by default when you install it. I'm here because I did that, and want to cut cost.